# How to understand asynchronous Meteor.call on the client side

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

I'm working on a Meteor project and want to get the return value of Meteor.call in template helpers on client side. At very first, I just set a variable in the call back function and get the variable's value outside the `Meteor.call`. I found out the code after `Meteor.call` doesn't execute at all. Then I searched a bit and use Session, it works. But I don't really understand the reason. Here's my original code and modified code. Can anyone explain a bit for me? Thanks!!

Original wrong code: html

```
 <div id="text-result-main">
   <h2>{{title}}</h2>
 </div>
```

js

```
Template.texts.helpers({
  title: function(){
    var index = Router.current().params.index;
    Meteor.call('getTitle', index,function(error, result){ 
       titles = result;
    });
    console.log(titles);
    return titles;
 }});
```

Collection text.js

```
Text = new Mongo.Collection("text");
Meteor.methods({
  'getTitle': function(myindex){
     return Text.findOne({index: myindex}).title;
  }});
```

The working code: js

```
Template.texts.helpers({
 title: function(){
      var index = Router.current().params.index;
      Meteor.call('getTitle', index,function(error, result){ 
        Session.set("titles",result);
      });
      console.log(Session.get("titles"));
     return Session.get("titles"); 
}});
```

Notice that I didn't publish Collection Text to the client at all because it's just so huge. Every time when I refresh the page when running the wrong code, I can't see the content of "title" or see it on the console. But when I set the session, it works. I don't really understand how it works here. Thanks

Comment: If you are having trouble with the async call (which you will, I can tell) just convert your `Meteor.call` to a synchrnous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two issues **Asynchronicity** and **Reactivity**

This affectation

```
Meteor.call('getTitle', index,function(error, result){ 
   titles = result;
});
```

inside the meteor call is executed but in a asynch way. So the return of your helper is immediately called, and return a empty value.

Try it out in the console of your browser.

But then, why your template render correctly with {{title}} when you use a Session Variable ? 
It's because the Session is a reactive data source, witch means that every change to it trigger a re-computation of all templates involving this piece of data.

Here is a timeline:

- Methods is called
- Return empty value
- Method is executed, setting variable value
- **If** the Variable is a reactive data source, template is re-computed. ( in your case, the session is a reactive data source. )

**To go further**

I would use a reactive var in that case, it's very close from a session variable, but the scope is limited to a template.

A good read on Reactive data source: http://richsilv.github.io/meteor/meteor-reactive-data-types/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the fact that `Meteor.call()` is asynchronous when paired with a callback.

So when `title()` starts executing, it does not wait for your `Meteor.call()` invocation to return a result (or possibly an error). It continues execution. This is called asynchronous execution.

In short, you are trying to log the value for the key `titles` which doesn't exist in `Session` (since the state of your asynchronous Meteor call is unknown, at this point of time).

Try moving the console log statement into the callback paired with your `Meteor.call()` and you can see the result once it has successfully been set in `Session`.

---

A workaround to your problem is to make your `Meteor.call()` synchronous like this:

```
Template.texts.helpers({
 title: function(){
      var index = Router.current().params.index;
      var result = Meteor.call('getTitle', index); // <--- this is synchronous code now
      Session.set("titles",result);
      console.log(Session.get("titles"));
      return Session.get("titles"); 
}});
```

Removing the callback makes `Meteor.call()` behave synchronously.

> If you do not pass a callback on the server, the method invocation
>   will block until the method is complete. It will eventually return the
>   return value of the method, or it will throw an exception if the
>   method threw an exception.

(from http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-call)

Comment: Hi! This actually doesn't really work in my code. I can only use asynchronous call and set the session within it.

Comment: Your code snippets suggested otherwise. Client side Session `sets` and `gets` are allowed in Meteor IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like this:

```
title: function(){
    var index = Router.current().params.index;
    var a = Text.findOne({index: myindex}).title;
    console.log(a);
    return a;
```

without methods

Comment: It's true that without more info, a method call is not mandatory here.

Comment: It's because my collection is too huge so the performance will be intolerable if I publish them to the client. Still thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Try using partial index on mongodb.Partial indexes only index the documents in a collection that meet a specified filter expression. So you will be only publishing subset of collection.